# Configure key material for SSL session tickets

Tags: ssl, openssl, erlang, tls1.3

I can see from the [Erlang TLS 1.3 documentation](https://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/ssl/using_ssl.html#session-tickets-and-session-resumption-in-tls-1.3) that we can enable session resumption on the server by setting, for eg.

```
{session_tickets, stateless},
```

The documentation also states

> Session tickets are protected by application traffic keys, and in stateless tickets, the opaque data structure itself is self-encrypted.

I take it, by *application traffic keys*, they mean the key provided in the `keyfile`. Is there any way to configure the session tickets to be protected/synchronized by some custom key material that can by distributed to many servers, so that clients can resume sessions against any of these servers?

OpenSSL has [`SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_ticket_key_cb`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_ticket_key_cb.html) which lets you manage tickets manually. I'm looking to do something similar in Erlang.